# Change ActionBarSherlock background color

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to implement ActionBarSherlock because I was told it is relatively easy to implement and customize.  I've found it was pretty easy to implement, but I'm trying to change the background color of the ActionBar and it's proving difficult.

According to the the site ([link](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html)), it seems you can inherit one of the ActionBarSherlock's themes and then override the properties you need.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.ActionBar" parent="Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow">
      <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
      <item name="background">#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I'm noticing the built-in theme are using images for the background, but I'm praying I don't have to create images to change the background color.

Thanks.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The action bar background color is defined in a style for the action bar, not in the theme itself. You'll need to do something like this:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#ff000000</item>
    <item name="background">#ff000000</item>
</style>
```

Be careful using colors defined in XML. `ColorDrawable` did not respect it's view bounds on pre-Honeycomb so if you use tab navigation with a separate background for the stacked tab view you will have problems.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not using tabs or anything, just a single ActionBar with some actions, so it's ok to use colors instead of images?  I'm using ActionBarSherlock on 8 different apps and I don't have the expertise to create images.

Comment: BTW, your code worked for adding the background color. Thanks.

Comment: It's safe to use colors so long as you are not using it for the stacked background attribute. The regular background and split background will fine but on pre-3.0 using a color for stacked will not display properly.

Comment: Sounds good.  Thanks for the responses and the great product.

Comment: @JakeWharton `actionBarStyle` requires `API Level 11`.  Is there a way to do it if targeting less than 11?  Actually I just realized that only `android:actionBarStyle` requires 11, though this still doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Figured out the problem.  Be sure to include the proper `value-v#` folder to apply styles to ranging API levels.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15339215/1747491) answer.

Comment: @JakeWharton I am developing with minimum api level of 9. It shows "actionBarStyle requires API level 11 (current min is 9)". It also shows "No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow'". What can i do help me out..

Comment: @JakeWharton Hey what do you meant by "did not respect it's view bounds on pre-Honeycomb so if you use tab navigation with a separate background for the stacked tab view you will have problems." ?

Answer (score 54):

I just used

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00853c")));
```

It changed the background color. Hope it helps.

Comment: @alicanbatur it is, but if you plan to have your own style in the ActionBar and use it along the whole app, it isn't very nice if you paste that line of code in every class where you wanna modify your background :)

Comment: its most simplest way :)

Answer (score 2):

The code mentioned by Jake Wharton is true. But when applying the code to the styles.xml may not work if you have minSDK<11 because android:actionBarStyle is supported in API-11+

To solve that error:

Make a folder of values-v11 in your res folder and create the XML file as mentioned above.