# Change ActionBar Tabs background color

Tags: android-actionbar, android

Is there a way to change the background color of the tab bar in the ActionBar without changing it in the one line version?

To clarify what I want: In portrait mode the ActionBar is split in two lines, the ActionBar itself and the tabs below. In landscape mode the tabs are in the actual ActionBar.

I want to change the background color of the portrait mode. If I change the background in the TabView it'll be changed for both modes. Do I have to create separate styles for those? Which brings up a second question: is there a way to know when it'll be two lines and when not?

Or am I just missing something?

I'm using ActionBarSherlock btw

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064411/change-actionbarsherlock-background-color

Comment: No the problem is not the background of the ActionBar, but the background of the Tab bar.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `android:backgroundStacked` attribute of the ActionBar style:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/my_stacked_background</item>
</style>
```

or (If using ActionBarSherlock):

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/my_stacked_background</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/my_stacked_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to make this work with the default holo light theme? What do you name it? What do you call in the manifest? This doesn't work.

Comment: @JesperB why we need to set both "android:backgroundStacked" and "backgroundStacked"?

Answer (score 23):

To Change Actionbar Tab's color, Pls use this code:

//For Example if you want White color as Tabs background, then

```
getActionBar().setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")));
```

Comment: This is the one answer which helped me after day. Styles are too complicated. This is the easiest way.

Comment: Why `mActionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(R.color.action_bar_bg));` does not work?

Answer (score 3):

In ActionBarSherlock's `values/abs__themes.xml` there is

```
<item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/abs__cab_background_bottom_holo_dark</item>
```

You have to create your own theme derived from ABS

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/my_split_background</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That's what I thought it might be, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Have you applied this theme to your application in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes. But it's the wrong value. If you look at the actual asset (abs__cab_background_bottom_holo_dark) the blue bar that's being used to show that it's selected is on top, not on bottom. Also there are no different modes for selected/unselected etc

Comment: Ok, there is also `<item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/abs__ab_bottom_transparent_dark_holo</item>` in `values/abs__styles.xml`. I don't remember the exact item name, but you have to look in that direction

Comment: It's backgroundStacked! Thanks for guiding me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.White);
actionBar.SetStackedBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

for xamarin folks.

Comment: A bit of explanation would improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

To seperate styles depending on orientation you have to create in your `/res` folder a new folder called `layout-land` (for landscape mode) and `layout-port` (in portrait mode) and put your xml files for action bar and set it's  specific style (with the color you want) on each folder.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that. But it's not just landscape/portrait. I assume on tablets it'll always be just one line. I know I can also have separate styles for large screens etc but I don't know what mode will be used in which configuration.