# How to Style ActionBar, tab background on selected tab

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-styles

I'm struggling with styling the ActionBar. My app has an ActionBar with three tabs. I'm trying to get the selected tab to have a background color, and the unselected tabs to show a different color. I'm following this reference: [Customizing Action Bar](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html). But all the TABs are showing the Selected color.

My `styles.xml` file is as follows:

```
<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_background</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">32dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">32dp</item>
</style> 

<style name="MyActionBarTabBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">

    <item name="android:background">@drawable/red</item>
</style> 


<style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Light</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabBarStyle</item>

</style>
```

tab_background is just a 9 patch. I'm also not sure if I'm inheriting the action bar tab from the correct parent (`parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar`). I've looked through the references & find it very difficult to understand the style hierarchy

Why wont my tabs show selected or no? Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Use [ActionBarSherlockStyleGenerator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100) to style it and use. Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269482/change-background-of-the-actionbarsherlock-alone-not-the-tabs/13283261#13283261)

Comment: Thanks Pravin. The ActionBarStyleGenerator is very useful to style ActionBar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved my problem. I didn't use State List Drawables initially. I used the background image directly instead of going via the StateListDrawable. Using StateListDrawable, you can set a different background based on whether the tag is selected or not.

So I added the file `tab_background_select.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_background" />

</selector>
```

and I referenced this from my `styles.xml`:

```
 <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_background_select</item>
```

Comment: What do you mean you referenced this from styles.xml? How did you reference it and in what way? How do I do that? I can't get it to work. Nothing works for this, it never changes no matter what I do. Android seems really buggy. What parent did you refernece? What did you name it? What did you reference in the manifest?

Comment: Nice answer :) use like this,`<style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_background_select</item>
    </style>`