# TabLayout tab style

Tags: android, android-design-library

I use new `TabLayout` from `com.android.support:design` library. I want to change background of the selected/unselected tabs.
I look at sources and found only `tabBackground` attribute that change all tabs colour and does not control selected tab colour.

How can I control selected/unselected tab background?

Comment: @Doraemon this article has awful code paddings and contains no information about `TabLayout`, sorry.

Comment: @jlopez Not duplicated, he is asking about `TabLayout`, not about actionBar tabs

Answer (score 201, accepted):

**Define:**

```
    <style name="AppTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabMaxWidth">@dimen/tab_max_width</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingStart">6dp</item>
        <item name="tabPaddingEnd">6dp</item>
        <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/AppTabTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/range</item>
    </style>

    <!-- for text -->
    <style name="AppTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
```

**Apply:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    style="@style/AppTabLayout"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTabTextAppearance"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    .... />
```

Comment: Where is something called selected tab background?

Comment: @Forte_201092 in `TabLayout` selected tab is indicated with `tabIndicatorColor`

Comment: So, in `TabLayout`, we cannot change the selected tab background?

Comment: @AnhTriet you have to define `drawable-selector` with two states: pressed and unpressed (or checked/unchecked I don't remember, you got the idea). And then set this selector to tabBackground. So you can control selected tab bg.

Comment: how to put a divider between two tabs?

Comment: @shuvro try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548875/how-to-add-margin-between-tabs-in-tablayout

Comment: Is there a way to set the tab background selector (to control the effect of pressing it, for example) via code, instead of XML ?

Answer (score 18):

If you look into the `TabLayout.class` you will notice inner `TabView.class` for tab's actual layout. It's same layout as any other with `isSelected` attribute. Selecting tab will also have impact on this so all you need to do is to create selector background drawable like

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/tab_bg_selected"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/tab_bg_unselected"/></selector>
```

and attach it to the tabBackground attribute e.g. in XML like

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_bg"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

I read [How to Style ActionBar, tab background on selected tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285490/how-to-style-actionbar-tab-background-on-selected-tab) and figure out what to do. It is really similar problem, but I found awesome solution specially for `TabLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/tab_layout_color"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="48dp"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/selected_tab_color"
    />
```

note that `layout_height` and `tabIndicatorHeight` have the same height. So you get pretty transition animation with this way.

Comment: This solution has one bug - indicator overlaps tab text

Answer (score -20):

I met this problem too. I just searched `tabIndicatorColor` in the whole project and found the following code in some `R.java`:

```
       @see #TabLayout_tabBackground
       @see #TabLayout_tabContentStart
       @see #TabLayout_tabGravity
       @see #TabLayout_tabIndicatorColor
       @see #TabLayout_tabIndicatorHeight
       @see #TabLayout_tabMaxWidth
       @see #TabLayout_tabMinWidth
       @see #TabLayout_tabMode
       @see #TabLayout_tabPadding
       @see #TabLayout_tabPaddingBottom
       @see #TabLayout_tabPaddingEnd
       @see #TabLayout_tabPaddingStart
       @see #TabLayout_tabPaddingTop
       @see #TabLayout_tabSelectedTextColor
       @see #TabLayout_tabTextAppearance
       @see #TabLayout_tabTextColor
```

So the problem is solved. May this will be some help for you.
i.e. I use IDEA

Comment: Why "problem is solved"? From this, how can we set the selected tab background?