# How do I change a tab background color when using TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-tablayout

This is my code in the main activity

```
public class FilterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    PageAdapter pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), FilterActivity.this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);



  }
}
```

And this is my code in the XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar">
    </include>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        android:layout_height="48dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to change the background color of one tab when it's selected

Answer (score 339, accepted):

What finally worked for me is similar to what @如果我是DJ suggested, but the `tabBackground` should be in the `layout` file and **not** inside the `style`, so it looks like:

**`res/layout/somefile.xml`**:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    ....
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
    ...
    />
```

and the selector
**`res/drawable/tab_color_selector.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: You can also add a color value to that attribute : ie : app:tabBackground:@color/colorAccent

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However, I lost default ripple effect with it.

Comment: How can I do this programatically?

Comment: @TSR, if you don't need different colors for each tab, you can do `tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(colorInt)`. If you need it for each tab, you can extract the children from your TabLayout

Comment: to improve look and feel, I think we should also add **state_pressed**: **<item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>**

Comment: How to change textColor as well? Can we achieve with same logic?

Comment: How do I set different tab background for specific tabs?

Answer (score 21):

You can try this:

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/background</item>
</style>
```

In your background xml file:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

Comment: and how to implement this?

Comment: Add property android:style to your TabLayout in XML.

Answer (score 15):

Add atribute in xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    ....
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
    ...
    />
```

And create in drawable folder, tab_color_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_background_unselected"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 14):

One of the ways I could find is using the tab indicator like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabBackground="@color/normal_unselected_color"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/selected_color"
    app:tabIndicatorGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="150dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/selected_text_color"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/unselected_text_color">

    ..... tab items here .....

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Trick is to:

- Make the tab indicator to align in center
- Make the indicator height sufficiently large so that it covers the whole tab

This also takes care of the smooth animation while switching tabs

Answer (score 7):

You can have it in the xml.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorGray"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

After some messing around this is how I got the desired look (at least in the emulator) and it keeps the ripple effect.

[image: tab layout with tab selector with color argument]

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
    app:tabIconTint="@drawable/tab_selector"
    app:tabIconTintMode="src_atop"
    app:tabTextColor="@drawable/tab_selector" />
```

And the `@drawable/tab_selector`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
</selector>
```

FYI: This is what the emulator showed before I added the `color` argument to `@drawable/tab_selector`:

[image: tab layout with tab selector without color argument]

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried checking the [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)?

You will need to create a listener for the [`OnTabSelectedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener.html) event, then when a user selects any tab you should check if it is the correct one, then change the background color using `tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(int color)`, or if it is not the correct tab make sure you change back to the normal color again with the same method.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but tabLayout changes the full tab widget color, and I can't find a method on tabLayout.Tab that only changes the tab color and the other tabs stay with the same color.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are after. If you only want to color the body of one tab then you can add a container/view inside that tab, then you should be able to set the container/view background color in the XML like normal, for example the following will set the background to red `android:background=FF0000`

Comment: These other questions/answers may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904138/how-to-change-the-new-tablayout-indicator-color-and-height
and
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30755351/1270000

Answer (score 2):

As I found best and suitable option for me and it will work with animation too.

You can use `indicator` it self as a background.

You can set **`app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"`** attribute to use as background.

Example:

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chef" />


        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: This is taking the accent color automatically. How to give it different color without changing the accent color. thanks

Comment: You can use `app:tabIndicatorColor` @MindRoasterMir

Answer (score 2):

Since ViewPager is tending to be replaced by ViewPager2 and we will need to migrate to it.

A quick work around using Java would be something like this:

```
    final List<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>(){
        {
            add("#FF0000");
            add("#800000");
            add("#FFFF00");
        }
    };

    
    ViewPager2 viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(your_data_structure);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    final TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.view.setAlpha((float) 0.5);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.view.setAlpha(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    TabLayoutMediator mediator = new TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewPager, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
            tab.setText("Tab" + position);
            
            /* 
            *  With this feature the TabIndicator color is ignored 
            *  or covered by the new color ex.(if alpha channel is changed the indicator can be seen through)
            */
            tab.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors.get(position))); //You can use your HEX string color
        }
    });

    mediator.attach();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the background or ripple color of each Tab like this:

```
    //set ripple color for each tab
    for(int n = 0; n < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); n++){

        View tab = ((ViewGroup)mTabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(n);

        if(tab != null && tab.getBackground() instanceof RippleDrawable){
            RippleDrawable rippleDrawable = (RippleDrawable)tab.getBackground();
            if (rippleDrawable != null) {
                rippleDrawable.setColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(rippleColor));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color of the tab by this attribute

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/tabs"
style="@style/CategoryTab"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
'android:background="@color/primary_color"/>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **tab.view.setBackground(drawable)**  in  **tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener**
as given below:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_rectangle_1345));
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another fix for some stubborn cases is to set background of TabLayout to shape selector as in this example:

tablayout_bg.xml at /res/drawable

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

fragment_layout.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tablayout_bg"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        >
```

Answer (score -3):

One of simplest solution is to change colorPrimary from colors.xml file.