# How can i change the background color for each tabs in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

[image]

here is my xml code but it is didnt work like pic

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="406dp"
    android:layout_height="94dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/teal_200"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/purple_200"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" >
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640563/how-do-i-change-a-tab-background-color-when-using-tablayout

Comment: thanks..but i dont want change when i select tab! i want each tab have backgroud color when i ran app