# TabLayout font can't be changed

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello Everyone i'm working on a tabbed app in which i have a toolbar reserved for the app logo and the tablayout with the tabs name in it,i wanted to change the font in those tabs names but i couldn't figure it out since the name are not actual textviews,i searched well in the forum and everywhere else but couldn't find anyone to answer that,so briefly what i want is to change the font in those tabs names here is my code thank you for helping!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

public Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);


}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    //here i set the fragments to use i have separate fragment.java
    // for each page i show that refers to another xml that shows the content
    //the words between "" are the tabs name and i need to change their fonts :(
    adapter.addFragment(new FiveFragment(),"ثقافة");
    adapter.addFragment(new FourFragment(), "فن");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "تعليم");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "تاريخ");
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "علوم");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

Here Is the main activity xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="323dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="330dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="#000"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#0ff"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: TabLayout has a getTabAt method, and that has a setText method, no?

Comment: My Question is actually related to the font changing i want to set a custom font to my tabs names sir ^^"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text size of android design TabLayout tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471177/text-size-of-android-design-tablayout-tabs)

Comment: I see. You haven't shown your styles.xml, but I think that post is what you are looking for

Comment: i don't want to chnage the size of the words,i want to change the font,please read my question again

Comment: It's just a link to show how to style the text of a tab. It's not important that the example given was only for the size of the text. You just add additional stuff to the styles.xml

Comment: well unfortunately it's not that easy i tried so hard can you help with a code example?

Answer (score 3):

You can set a custom style to your TabLayout to change the font.

## Using Styles

Create a new style in your `styles.xml` :

```
<style name="AppTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/YourTextAppareance</item>
</style>
```

Then set a `YourTextAppareance` style.

```
<style name="YourTextAppareance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
```

Finally, set the style to your TabLayout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        style="@style/AppTabLayout"
        app:tabTextColor="#000"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

Taken from this : [TabLayout tab style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754203/tablayout-tab-style)

## Using Custom Views

An alternative way to do this is to use custom views and setup your fonts in the layout of the custom view. But this is a more complex way to do this because you must handle the views when "selected" and "not selected".

```
public class SectionsPageAdapter  extends FragmentPageViewAdapter {

public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public View getCustomView(int position, View v, boolean selected) {

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(App.getApplication());
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.view_tab, null);
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    // Change your font on the textview here.

    textView.setText(getPageTitle(position));

    // Take in account the selected var if you want another layout when
    // tab is selected.

    return v;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    if (position == 0)
        return Fragment.newInstance();
    else if (position == 1)
        return Fragment.newInstance();
    else
        return Fragment.newInstance();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.

    return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Tab 1";
        case 1:
            return "Tab 2";
        case 2:
            return "Tab 3";
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Then, juste browse the list of your tabs and add the custom view.

```
for (int i=1; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++)
{
    tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCustomView(i, null, false));
}
```

Don't forget to check onPageSelected changes to update the views :

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
                if (i == position)
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCustomView(i, tabLayout.getTabAt(i).getCustomView(), true));
                else
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCustomView(i, tabLayout.getTabAt(i).getCustomView(), false));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

For reminder, here it is how to change the font programmatically :

```
Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf");
newfont.setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: can you refer how to this with a custom font please?

Comment: Not available on styles by default. If you supports only API7+, here is a library that seems to allow this [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

Comment: i think that this library is broken i've been trying with it for 1 hour now and the app crashes everytime i use it :/

Comment: A lot of librairies implement custom fonts on styles, just check it on github. In case of, I edited my post to present an alternative (but not optimal) way that should work without any additional librairies.

Comment: i applied the calligraphy library so well but the it's applying for the toolbar and the fragmentseven for the navigation drawer  but not for the tabs names! :( , thanks for helping so far ^^"

Comment: @AnasHaxer I'm working ona similar problem. Did you find a solution to this? If you did do share it.