# how to insert tabview in a linear layout?

Tags: android, frontend, android-tablayout

[how to make this type of android layout? actually the tablayout is always at the top of a layout but I want to make this kind of layout having tabs after some other content, I don't know how to initiate with this layout?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv7tO.jpg)

Comment: You can use a regular `TabLayout` and style the tabs to look like what you showed in the image. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754203/tablayout-tab-style).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The UI component named Payments is probably not **tabs** but **Filter chips**
.Check out this article for reference:
[Filter and Choice Chips Medium article](https://medium.com/@werder630/material-filter-and-choice-chips-d929312148d8)